# How to add help text at the bottom of result list for Jquery Typeahead?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I built an autocompleted using [jquery typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/overview/) because it has tons of options and most of them meets my requirements.

But instead of its default option, I want to add some help text at the bottom of the result list like this:

[image]

I inspected the its element and insert it with pure Jquery Script, but it does not work as expected.

```js
$.typeahead({    
  input: '.js-typeahead-country_v1',
      order: "desc",
      source: {        
    data: [            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",             "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",             "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",             "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",             "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",             "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the",             "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti",             "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",             "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon",             "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea",             "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India",             "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan",             "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",             "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",             "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",             "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Monaco",             "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",             "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",             "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino",             "Sao Tome", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone",             "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain",             "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan",             "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",             "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",             "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"        ]    
  },
      callback: {        
    onInit: function(node) {            
      console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);        
    }    
  }
});

$('.typeahead__result').append('<span class="help">Use up/down arrow keys to navigate. Press Enter to select</span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.min.js" integrity="sha512-Rc24PGD2NTEGNYG/EMB+jcFpAltU9svgPcG/73l1/5M6is6gu3Vo1uVqyaNWf/sXfKyI0l240iwX9wpm6HE/Tg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.css" integrity="sha512-AQG3JVpy/h0TsLsFs/HDLjnkq1ih9uUliGGXdQ7LQcGQt7GD+1b7HWOQ2oeCH7tKdtrfRg75CGApafi+//9Dbw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="typeahead__container">

  <div class="typeahead__field">

    <div class="typeahead__query">
      <input class="js-typeahead-country_v1" name="country_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="typeahead__button">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, is there any way I can achieve this help text correctly like in the picture? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onLayoutBuiltBefore` callback to decorate the list before it's displayed. In this example I've added it to the end of the list, with the `.help` class for styling.

```js
$.typeahead({
  input: '.js-typeahead-country_v1',
  order: "desc",
  source: {
    data: ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Monaco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"]
  },
  callback: {
    onLayoutBuiltBefore: function(node, query, result, resultHtmlList) {
      if (resultHtmlList) {
        resultHtmlList.append(
          $('<li/>', {
            "text": "Use up/down arrow keys to navigate. Press Enter to select",
            "class": "help"
          })
        );
      }
      return resultHtmlList;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.min.js" integrity="sha512-Rc24PGD2NTEGNYG/EMB+jcFpAltU9svgPcG/73l1/5M6is6gu3Vo1uVqyaNWf/sXfKyI0l240iwX9wpm6HE/Tg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.css" integrity="sha512-AQG3JVpy/h0TsLsFs/HDLjnkq1ih9uUliGGXdQ7LQcGQt7GD+1b7HWOQ2oeCH7tKdtrfRg75CGApafi+//9Dbw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="typeahead__container">

  <div class="typeahead__field">

    <div class="typeahead__query">
      <input class="js-typeahead-country_v1" name="country_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="typeahead__button">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#find-subj" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```